# kmlLayer not displaying google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

First time ever posting on StackOverflow so tell me and be crude if I am doing something terribly wrong anyway. I recently created a KML file with maps.google.com and I uploaded the kml to my site, and I am trying to implement to the google maps that we created, but I am stumped as I have no errors but it does not show at all.

```
// North Campus SHuttle KML implementation
var redShuttle = new google.maps.KmlLayer (
     'http://blazelist.org/maps/test/RedShuttle.kml'
     );
redShuttle.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you share more code?

In my example your code is working:

```
function initialize()
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.7964,73.8456),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
  /*  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://blazelist.org/maps/test/RedShuttle.kml',
    {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
    });
    */
    var redShuttle = new google.maps.KmlLayer ( 'http://blazelist.org/maps/test/RedShuttle.kml' ); redShuttle.setMap(map);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/WbzpS/

Comment: [link](http://sdrv.ms/15A1Ybq) here is a link to my maps html file (sorry I don't have a programming background).